# How to select both Min & Max across entire query using EF Core?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to write a query where it only needs to ping the db once. Currently I have:

```cs
var postQuery = context.Posts.Where(...);
var min = postQuery.Min(d => d.Start);
var max = postQuery.Max(d => d.End);
```

Is there a way to combine this into a single select statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, it's a bit tricky but here it is:

```cs
var result = context.Posts.Where(...)
    .GroupBy(p => 1) // Group by a constant to get a single row result
    .Select(g => new
    {
        MinStart = g.Min(p => p.Start),
        MaxEnd = g.Max(p => p.End)
    })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```